# Extracting each line separately in an Image using python

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, scikit-image, hough-transform

[image]I have a binary image in which some lines are there at **arbitrary angles**( line pixels have some non zero value(suppose 1) and rest of the image having pixel values as zero).I have to extract each line separately(For Example, if there are 5 lines in an image,I can store the collection of pixels of each line into 5 separate lists) but I am unable to do so. I have utilised Hough line and hough line peaks of scikit-image which results in houghspace, angles and distances, but I am unable to utilise them to create such separate collection of pixels.Kindly guide and share the code if possible.(For illustration purpose,the image is attached.)

Comment: Is your image really as clean as that? With no noise? With perfectly continuous lines? Do the lines sometimes intersect?

Comment: @Mark Setchell -Yes the image is clean in fact it is a binary mask with no noise. In addition, the lines are continuous and yes they can intersect(the image attached is just for illustration purpose,consider the case of intersecting lines also).